# How to plot the two classes so that they are distinguishable?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

In the following piece of code, how can I tell it to plot data of each class with a different sign, like x and circle:

```
C_11=[3;3.5;4;4.5;5;5.5;7];
C_12=[15;16;17];
C_1=[C_11;C_12];
C_21=[0;0.5;1;2];
C_22=[8;9;10;11;12;13];
C_23=[20;25;30];
C_2=[C_21;C_22;C_23];

%to make the two classes linearly separable
mu_11=MEAN(C_11);
mu_12=MEAN(C_12);
S_11=VAR(C_11,1,1);
S_12=VAR(C_12,1,1);

x=[C_1;C_2]
y= exp(-0.5*(abs(x-mu_11))./S_11)+exp(-0.5*(abs(x-mu_12))./S_12);
x_new=ones([23 2])
plot(x,y,'r+')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Marker` property.

As a simple example:

```
x = 1:100;
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);

plot(x, y1, 'Marker', 'x', 'Color', 'blue');
hold ('on');
plot(x, y2, 'Marker', 'o', 'Color', 'red');
```

You can find other line properties [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line_props.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
plot(x1,y1,'ro',x2,y2,'bx')
```

`ro` and `bx` here indicates markers (their color and type).

Answer (score 1):

You can call plot multiple times with a different argument. Use `hold on` to save the old lines.